# Running GNU parallel --sem hangs on SGE Cluster

Tags: bash, cluster, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run 3 commands in parallel on an SGE cluster, e.g.

```
cmds=("prog 1 2 3" "prog 4 5 6" "prog 7 8 9")
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"
do
    sem -j 3 $cmd
done
sem --wait
```

So, my commands execute and complete successfully which I infer from the output logs generated and the fact that I can see they're not running on the node anymore.  But then sem --wait waits for an indefinite period of time when I submit with qsub.  Alternatively, I've run in interactive mode and a. manually typed the commands and b. sourced the shell script; both of these methods successfully finished.  Is there something that I'm missing about running sem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: sem needs write access to $HOME/.parallel. Maybe you do not have that on SGE? You might instead use: parallel -j3 ::: "${cmds[@]}"

Comment: It was tricky for me to get my script changed (ran into some unrelated issues), but your suggestion worked Ole.  Thank you for your help, and for parallel itself - I'm finding it quite useful.  Still strikes me as odd sem doesn't work for me, but I'm happy for now with this solution.

Comment: To change a bigger script you can often use a bash function: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Calling-Bash-functions

Comment: Good suggestion.  My commands are quite a bit more complicated than the example I gave and that would help simplify them for clarity.

Comment: Ole, I'm having difficulty using parallel with a bash function and multiple arguments, e.g.:
`z=("1 2" "3 4");
f() { echo $2 $1; }
$parallel f ::: "${z[@]}";
1 2
3 4`  

is the output rather than the expected:  
    2 1  
    4 3

Comment: Ok, well it looks like I've come up with a method that's working for me: `z=("1 2" "3 4"); f() { IFS=" " read -a arr <<< "$1"; echo "${arr[1]}" "${arr[0]}"; }; export -f f; parallel f ::: "${z[@]}"` does indeed yield `2 1\n4 3`.

Comment: -N2 may also work if you want GNU Parallel to pass 2 args at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You're running each command sequentially.  By the time the script gets to `sem --wait`, all three commands have run and finished.

Try adding an `&` to the `sem -j 3 $cmd` line.  This will run each command in the background, in parallel.

```
cmds=("prog 1 2 3" "prog 4 5 6" "prog 7 8 9")
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"
do
    sem -j 3 $cmd &
done
sem --wait
```

Comment: This is not how `sem` works. Also program works for the poster if run locally.